# number of ordered pair subsets $B$ and $C$ of $A$ such that $B$ and $C$ have exactly one element in common

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

My question is

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then what is the number of ordered pairs of  subsets $B$ and $C$ of $A$ such that $B$ and $C$ have exactly one element in common?

Answer (score 4):

Pick one element of $A$ as the unique element of $B\cap C$. Then assign the rest of the elements of $A$ to one of the three possibilities $\in B$, $\in C$, $\notin B\cup C$. That makes $|A|\cdot 3^{|A|-1}$.

Comment: Will you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 1):

One element can be selected by $6$ ways.
Now for each other element, there are three possibilities:

1. it'll be only in $B$
2. it'll be only in $C$
3. it'll be in $B \cup C$.

Since other than the selected element, there are $5$ elements, for each of them,

there are three possibilities.
No. of such sets:

(using Fundamental Principle of Counting) $$6\times3\times3\times3\times3\times3=6\cdot(3)^5$$